# Combining Multiple Value Json Payload using Azure APIM policies

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-policy

Hi I have a current payload in APIM, which I want to transform into another payload.

Current Payload:

```json
{
  "insurance_id": "2112",

  "insurer_info": {
    "first": "Tony",
    "last": "Stark"
  }
}
```

Expected Payload

```json
{
  "id": "2112",
  "insurer_name": {
    "fullname": "Tony Stark"
  }
}
```

Attempt of the code:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="ok" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);

                var transformedBody = new JObject();
                transformedBody["id"] = body["insurance_id"];
                

                var insurerName= new JObject();
                dependentee["fullname"] = body["insurer_info"]["first"]["last"];
                transformedBody["insurerName"] = insurerName;


                return transformedBody.ToString();               
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to extract first and last name from the current payload. And show as full name as shown in the expected payload. What I have implemented above is wrong, and I dont understand how I can go about combining values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the JObject:
`var insurerInfo = body["insurer_info"] as JObject;`

You are getting the fullname with string concatination:

`var fullName = insurerInfo["first"]?.Value<string>() + " " + insurerInfo["last"]?.Value<string>();`

The complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="ok" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);

                var transformedBody = new JObject();
                transformedBody["id"] = body["insurance_id"];
                
                var insurerInfo = body["insurer_info"] as JObject;
                if(insurerInfo != null)
                {
                    var fullName = insurerInfo["first"]?.Value<string>() + " " + insurerInfo["last"]?.Value<string>();
                    var insurerName = new JObject();
                    insurerName["fullname"] = fullName;
                    transformedBody["insurerName"] = insurerName;
                }

                return transformedBody.ToString();               
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

BTW: Please take care about your copied code from other questions: `dependentee` does not exist here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "set body liquid template" like this:

```
<set-body template="liquid">
{
  "id": "{{body.insurance_id}}",
  "insurer_name": {
    "fullname": "{{body.insurer_info.first}} {{body.insurer_info.last}}"
 }
}
</set-body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use C# for this(Little bit harder than the next but got a lot of features) or use Liquid template(Easy to work with JSON)

Liquid( This template does not work in <return-response> )  
DOC: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/template/

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
        <set-body template="liquid">
            {
                "insurance_id": "2112",
                "insurer_info": {
                    "first": "Tony",
                    "last": "Stark"
                }
            }
        </set-body>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            {
                "id": "{{ body.insurance_id }}",
                "insurer_name": {
                    "fullname": "{{ body.insurer_info.first }} {{ body.insurer_info.last }}"
                }
            }
        </set-body>
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

C#

```
        <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <set-body template="liquid">
                {
                    "insurance_id": "2112",
                    "insurer_info": {
                        "first": "Tony",
                        "last": "Stark"
                    }
                }
            </set-body>
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body template="none">@{
                    JObject body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: false);
                    JObject response = new JObject {
                        ["id"] = body["insurance_id"],
                        ["insurer_name"] = new JObject {
                            ["fullname"] = $"{body["insurer_info"]["first"]} {body["insurer_info"]["last"]}"
                        }
                    };
                    return response.ToString();
                }</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```